# How to choose what file to open?

Tags: c, input, struct

I have the function but, after I insert the function in the main is it possible for the user when the program starts, to type in the filename (because more files available) and if exists it opens otherwise not?

```
void readFromFile(struct varor reg[], int *nrOfGoods){
        FILE * fp;
        fp = fopen("list.txt","r");
        if(fp!=NULL){
            char namn[WORDLENGTH];
            int varunummer, lagersaldo, i;

            fscanf(fp,"%d", nrOfGoods);//I have the quantity in the beggining of the file

            for(i=0;i<(*nrOfGoods);i++){
                fscanf(fp,"%d", &reg[i].varunummer);
                fscanf(fp,"%s", reg[i].namn);
                fscanf(fp,"%d", &reg[i].lagersaldo);

            }

            fclose(fp);
        } else printf("Could not open file.");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this, you can create strings which store filename when the user inputs it and use the filename as shown in the text below.

```
char filename[20];
printf("Enter the name of the file\n");
gets(filename);
infile=fopen(filename,"r"); 
if (infile == NULL)
   {
    printf("Could not open file %s",filename);

   }
 else
   {
     do something
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code, it seems pretty simple to fix, if what you want to do is open files other than "list.txt". Remember that in the function definition of fopen, looking like this:
`FILE *fopen(const char *filename, const char *mode)` [found here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fopen.htm).
The filename you open is a `const`. Contrary to what it seems to suggest, it doesn't mean that you can only use a string literal, just that the variable will not be modified or destroyed during the runtime of the function; it assures you that your filename variable will be kept intact.

So, since it doesn't require a literal, you can pass a variable as the first (and second) arguments. Just let the user input a string representing the filepath, then pass it to your method.